# Saving entities with user defined primary key values

Tags: spring-data-jdbc

I'm quite new to the Spring Data JDBC library, but so far I'm really impressed.

Unfortunately JDBC driver for my database (SAP Hana) doesn't support retrieving of generated keys after INSERT (implementation of method `PreparedStatement.getGeneratedKeys()` throws `UnsupportedOperationException`).

Therefore I decided, that I'll not use the generated keys and will define the PK values before saving (+ implement `Persistable.isNew()`). However even if the PK values are defined before saving, whenever an INSERT operation is triggered, it fails on the error, that the generated keys can't be retrieved.

After investigating source code of the affected method (`DefaultDataAccessStrategy.insert`) I've recognized, that there is every time executed the JDBC operations `update` method with the `KeyHolder` parameter.

I've (naively) tweaked the code with following changes and it started to work:

- if the PK is already defined, the JDBC operations `update` method without the `KeyHolder` is invoked
- such PK is then immediately returned from the method

Following code snippet from the tweaked `insert` method illustrates the changes.

```java
        Object idValue = getIdValueOrNull(instance, persistentEntity);
        if (idValue != null) {
            RelationalPersistentProperty idProperty = persistentEntity.getRequiredIdProperty();
            addConvertedPropertyValue(parameterSource, idProperty, idValue, idProperty.getColumnName());
            /* --- tweak start --- */
            String insertSql = sqlGenerator.getInsert(new HashSet<>(parameterSource.getIdentifiers()));
            operations.update(insertSql, parameterSource);
            return idValue;
            /* --- tweak end --- */
        }
```

So, the question is, if similar change can be implemented in the Spring Data JDBC to support also such use case as mine.

Comment: This is the wrong forum to discuss changes to Spring Data JDBC. Please raise an issue at https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jdbc/issues

Comment: Thank you. Here is the issue - https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jdbc/issues/933

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is basically a feature request which should be (and by now is) on the issue tracker of Spring Data JDBC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question can be considered as closed as the related feature request is registered in the issue tracker.

Comment: I think you should be able to close your question using a link under the tags for your question.

Comment: I don't have enough reputation yet, so I don't have such link. I've to accept own answer (after "timeout"), which should close the question (at least this I've Googled).